# Avoiding SQL injection in delete API function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, mysqli

I'm trying to build an android app, and part of the app involves CRUD options on a database that then need to be synced to the server. I have the CRU bits sorted, but am trying to do the deletes in such a way as to avoid SQL injection.

I have used prepared statements for all my other queries, but am wondering whether the following method that doesn't is safe:

I have defined a list of the tables on which a delete query is valid, along with a list of the primary keys on those tables that can be present in the `tableKey` field. Then I use a prepared statement using the value provided in the `tableKeyValue` field, along with restricting operations to those acting on an individual user's id.

Is this methodology safe from an SQL injection point of view, or should I set up specific API endpoints for each of the tables to be deleted from, and just pass through an Id value to be used in a traditional prepared statement?

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($deleteArray); $i++) {
        if (in_array($deleteArray[$i]['tableName'], $this->TABLE_ARRAY) && in_array($deleteArray[$i]['tableKey'], $this->KEY_ARRAY)) {
            $deleteStmtSQL = "DELETE FROM ".$deleteArray[$i]['tableName']." WHERE ".$deleteArray[$i]['tableKey']." = ? AND userId = ?";
            $deleteStmtSth = $this->dbh->prepare($deleteStmtSQL);
            $deleteStmtData = array(
                $deleteArray[$i]['tableKeyValue'],
                $userId
            );
            $deleteStmtSth->execute($deleteStmtData);
            $j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would argue that unless this function can internally guarantee that `$deleteArray` will always contain safe values, any implicit trust of those values as executable SQL code is a potential SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @David That's why I was asking for some clarification I suppose - if I'm checking that both `$deleteArray[$i]['tableName']` and `$deleteArray[$i]['tableKey']` are part of a pre-approved, closed list of values, then is there still a SQL injection risk?

Comment: That certainly mitigates the risk, though at that point I wonder if it's introducing more complexity than simply creating separate operations for the different tables.  Are there so many tables that it's prohibitive?  Perhaps a single object can expose many table-specific methods which delegate (using hard-coded values) to a private method that does what the posted code does?  That way while the *function* isn't guaranteeing safety, the *object* is.  As long as the scope of variables used to construct that query is small and easy to maintain at a glance, it should be fine.

Comment: Sort of `if (tableName == "foo") {call bar(id)}`? Thank you for the advice! There are about 8 different tables as possibilities.

Comment: @Authentik8: It is *never* safe to variables directly into an SQL query. This applies to table names, too. Aside from security issues, it can break your queries when e.g. you use reserved terms by accident. → You need to get to the point where it *physically* hurts to see variables inserted directly into SQL queries. ;)

Comment: @lxg I take your point, and yes, in every other database interaction in my api, I use prepared statements via PDO. My question is whether if, after checking that the tableName and tableKey variables exist within a defined list,  there is still an injection risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from lxg and David, this is the solution I have come up with:

I pass in the `tableName`, `tableKey` and `tableKeyValue` into a generic method, which, after confirming that the `tableName` and `tableKey` match up, the passes the `tableKeyValue` into a private method

(e.g. `deleteFromTableXByKey($tableKeyValue)` which then uses a prepared statement, taking only the key as a value.

If the values passed into the parent function for `tableName` and `tableKey` do not match up with the predefined list, then they pass through with no further interaction, and an error message is returned.